# Java Spring метод который помечен @Async() и @Transactional() тормозит

Tags: java, spring

Java Spring метод который помечен @Async() и @Transactional() тормозит

Почему, когда отрабатывает метод

```
List<OnlinerCatalog> onlinerCatalogDb = getOnlinerCatalogAndChildren();
```

Скорость перебора метода “test(Onliner onliner)”, падает примерно в 100 раз?
Причем если убрать аннотацию @Transactional() или закомментировать строку “List onlinerCatalogDb = getOnlinerCatalogAndChildren();” , то всё работает быстро

```
@Service
@EnableAsync
public class OnlinerStructureService {

    @Value("${upload.onlinerStructure}")
    private String pathStructure;


    @Autowired
    private OnlinerProductRepo onlinerProductRepo;

    @Autowired
    private OnlinerCatalogRepo onlinerCatalogRepo;


    @Transactional()
    @Async()
    public void onlinerStructureLoading() {
        System.out.println("Читаем каталог онлайнера из файла");
        Onliner onliner = readStructureFromFile();

        System.out.println("Обрабатываем модели онлайнера");
        test(onliner);
    }




    public void test(Onliner onliner) {

        List<OnlinerCatalog> onlinerCatalogDb = getOnlinerCatalogAndChildren();

        int countOnlinerModelId = 0;
        for (Category elCategory : onliner.getCategory()) {
            for (Vendor elVendor : elCategory.getVendor()) {
                for (Model elModel : elVendor.getModel()) {
                    int onlinerModelId = elModel.getId();
                    boolean isAnyOneTrue = onlinerProductRepo.existsByOnlinerId(onlinerModelId);
                    countOnlinerModelId++;
                    System.out.println("onlinerModelId - " + countOnlinerModelId); // печатаем сколько элементов обработано
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public List<OnlinerCatalog> getOnlinerCatalogAndChildren() {         // Получаем наш каталог онлайнера (структуру)
        List<OnlinerCatalog> onlinerCatalog = onlinerCatalogRepo.findAll();
        for (OnlinerCatalog el : onlinerCatalog) { // Заполняем чилдренов
            List<OnlinerCatalog> children = onlinerCatalog.stream().filter((с) -> с.getParentId() == el.getId()).sorted(Comparator.comparing(value -> value.getCategoryName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
            el.setChildren(children);
        }
        return onlinerCatalog;
    }

    public Onliner readStructureFromFile() {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Onliner.class);
            javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller un = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            return (Onliner) un.unmarshal(new File(pathStructure));
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: потому что транзакции - штуки небыстрые?

Comment: Быстрые. Почему тогда если закомментировать метод "getOnlinerCatalogAndChildren();", то работает быстро?

Comment: Это не очевидно разве? Потому что код, что вы комментируте, выбирает все записи из БД, что видимо операция ещё более медленная.

Comment: Вообще не очевидно, выбрал он все записи из БД, и пошел дальше, то что он выбрал даже нигде не используется. Непонятно каким образом эта выборка тормозит код, который находится после неё. И почему без аннотации @Transactional() всё работает быстро

Comment: Ну, мне жалко время тратить на такие споры. Вы так уверенно пишете, будем считать что вы правы, а я не прав. Желаю вам найти ответы на ваши вопросы.

Comment: Причем здесь споры. Разобраться хочу, что не так, но непонятно куда копать. Если вам очевидно, то объясните мне на пальцах почему так получается...

Comment: ну а как вом объяснить? Вот я вам написал, что транзакции медленные. А вы говорите, что они быстрые. Вы что то сделали, как то исследовали этот вопрос? Вы знаете, что такое транзакция на уровне БД? Или почему получение данных не оборачивают в транзакцию? Почитайте, на эту тему информации полный интернет.

Comment: Потом, вам не очевидно, что вы выбираете все заптси из таблицы. Ну а вот это что делает? `onlinerCatalogRepo.findAll();` Вы смотрели, что такое Spring репозитории и как они работают?

Comment: Вы работаете с какой то БД, так? Вы смотрели профайлер БД? Какие вы запросы туда шлете? Поглядите, там будет написано что происходит. Вы как то логгировали/профилировали свой код? Вы же знаете, что есть профайлеры, которые вам даже строчку покажут где у вас тормозит? Вы хотите разобраться - вот вам идеи на исследования.

Comment: Про профайлеры я не в курсе, попробую разобраться. Может есть другой способ  более простой и понятный как выполнить долгий метод в фоне и чтоб Хибернейт не терял сессию во время его выполнения?

Comment: я бы начал с определения конкретных мест где тормозит. Например, если вы только читаете из БД, но не пишете, то вам не нужен Transactional. Потом я бы попробовал выяснить, сколько и каких запросов  вы в БД шлете - возможно, их количестко можно сокртить. Далее я бы глядел в сторону оптимизации запросов (если есть что оптимизировать). НО вам все равно надо иметь инструмент, который покажет, помогают ваши действия или нет.